Chrome extension communicationPanel permission problem
Today my chrome extension was rejected from store because of using communicationPanel permission but I cant find any information how to remove this permission from my extension.
In my manifest I have only folowing permissions defined:

"permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "storage", "scripting", "unlimitedStorage", "sidePanel"]


Violation reference ID: Purple Potassium
Violation: Requesting but not using the following permission(s):
communicationPanel
How to rectify: Remove the above permission(s)
Any one have any clue how to fix this problem ?

